# How to add `includePaths` to Sass loader with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sass, sass-loader, webpacker

I overrode the sass-loader configuration to include the node_modules path:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.prepend('sass', {
    test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'style-loader'
    }, {
        loader: 'css-loader'
    }, {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            includePaths: ['node_modules'],
        }
    }]
})

module.exports = environment
```

Webpack compiles without errors, however it does not output an application.css pack anymore.

I made the change, because NPM plugins I imported from my Sass files who imported code from other plugins were causing errors when compiling.

Comment: @DayOne Where is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
environment.loaders.get('sass').use.find(item => item.loader === 'sass-loader').options.includePaths = ['node_modules']
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/3-x-stable/docs/webpack.md

Comment: Where did you figure out how to add a loader?  I'm trying to add the css-loader and the style-loader, but I have no idea how to get them to work.

What does your actual css import look like?

Comment: @Csteele5 This Github issue mentions it: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/782 and this section here in the Webpacker docs, although not specific to sass-loader explains how: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#overriding-loader-options-in-webpack-3-for-css-modules-etc